# How to write a SOQL query to order by records a user has ever modified?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object

Imagine I'm building a ticketing system and I want agents to automatically receive the "next" Ticket__c. However, I want to be smart about what comes next by adding some kind of best effort stickiness to the system where you'll work on tickets you had previously worked with before working on other tickets.

I want to sort by 4 things:

1. User owns the ticket
2. Owner has modified the ticket at any point in the past
3. The current User is in the same User.Group__c as the current Owner of the ticket
4. Date the ticket was created (this one is easy of course)

My biggest challenge is figuring out how to query for all of this and add it all into an ORDER BY clause so I can query tons of objects quickly and efficiently.

For #2, how would I query from something a User has every modified? One thought was to create a text field with a space delimited list of Ids of people who have ever modified the proof, then I could query `WHERE ModifiedIds__c LIKE ('%' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '%')` or something of that intent. However, I'm not sure how to add that into ORDER BY.

For #3, if Group__c is a custom field on the user, do I have to copy the current owner's Group__c to the object through a trigger and then index the field to both make it accessible and performant? Since Owner is polymorphic, I can't query by Owner.Group__c = . Right?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot see everyone who has ever modified a record, only the most recent. You could parse through the field history and compile that information but it would not be trivial.

Comment: Given your willingness to use triggers for #2; you should create a master-detail relationship to an auditHistory__c custom object where you record who worked on a ticket and dateTime.

Comment: @AdrianLarson that's why I was thinking of using a trigger to write the ID of every user who has touched a record into a text field, then I could use a formula to see if the current user's ID was in that text field. However, I'm not sure if I can get the performance I need when searching millions of rows.

Comment: @crop1645 that could work and I already actually have a master detail with some of that info, but let's say I have a detail auditHistory__c, how do I say put records with a detail where auditHistory__c.OwnerId == currentUser's ID before all other records with ORDER BY in SOQL?

Comment: If you have the audit history you could get the records in a wrapper and implement the comparable interface to do your custom sorting....

Comment: The challenge here is sorting everything at once to find the top object with all 4 conditions. If there are hundreds of thousands of possible objects, I'll need the database to ideally do most if not all of the sorting. However, maybe this would be easier with a separate query for 1, 2, 3 each ordered by 4 limit 1, then taking the first result. The potential issue here is latency of making multiple requests which will add latency for the user. Instantaneous response time is key.

Comment: how about a checkbox/boolean formula field in the detail record `is_auditdetail_from_runningUser__c` ? Then the database can sort for you

Comment: @crop1645 I'll have to try this out, but the tricky part here is that you can't index that - but this might be the case with anything user specific.